# Nginx running in Docker, reverse proxying to localhost outside of Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

As a workaround for some operational silliness in a work project, I am trying to:

1. Run Service A listening on `localhost:4001` and Service B listening `localhost:4002`.
2. Run Nginx inside a Docker container; internally listening on `0.0.0.0:80`
3. Set up Docker listening on localhost:80 on the host system, forwarding requests to port 80 in the Nginx container.
4. Set up Nginx to forward `localhost:80/a` to `localhost:4001`, and to forward `localhost:80/b` to `localhost:4002`.

I can write my own `nginx.conf` file, but for operational and organizational reasons I am stuck with running Nginx inside Docker.

But is it possible to have the Nginx server running inside a container proxy requests to the loopback device *of the host system*?

A diagram of what I am attempting to do:

```
                     ┌──────────────────┐
                     │                  │
                     │ My web browser   │─┐
                     └──────────────────┘ │
                                          │
         ┌────────────────────────────────┼───────┐
         │                                │       │
         │      ┌──────────────────────┐  │       │
         │      │                      │← │       │
     ┌───┼──────│ Nginx (0.0.0.0:80)   │──┘       │
     │ ┌─┼──────│                      │          │
     │ │ │      └──────────────────────┘          │
     │ │ │                                        │
     │ │ │ Docker (localhost:80 -> 172.17.0.1:80) │
     │ │ └────────────────────────────────────────┘
     │ └────────────────────────────┐
     │                              │
    ↓│                             ↓│
 ┌───────────────────────────┐  ┌───────────────────────────┐
 │                           │  │                           │
 │ Daemon A (localhost:4001) │  │ Daemon B (localhost:4002) │
 └───────────────────────────┘  └───────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: By definition, `localhost` is not accessible from the network, virtual or otherwise.

Comment: @DanielB as in, the loopback device of my machine is definitionally inaccessible from the virtual network inside Docker? Is there some workaround?

Comment: If the answer is "no, it's 100% impossible" then that's fine and I will accept it @DanielB.

Comment: Nothing is impossible.  // Perhaps elaborate on the restrictions that are forcing you to not run nginx on the host so we get a clearer picture on what methods could be used to work around that.

Comment: @DanielB the restriction is that this is the "local dev" setup for a handful of developers, and we don't want to force them to install and set up Nginx locally. Personally I don't think it's a big deal to set up Nginx, but the expectation is that we run as much as possible inside Docker, and only occasionally should developers be running services outside of containers. In this example, the service simply isn't "Dockerized" yet. I intend this to be a short-term hack to keep the other devs from having to think about ops stuff.

Comment: Hm so if it’s not (really) a security concern, would it perhaps be acceptable to run the Docker container in the host network namespace?

Comment: That would be fine, I thnk. I didn't even know that was possible. There might be other services running inside containers, but their ports will already be mapped to ports on the host network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, applications listening on `localhost` (`127.0.0.1/8` or `::1/128`) are accessible only locally on the same machine. Or, strictly speaking, from the same network namespace. By default, Docker containers have their own network namespace, which comes with another, separate instance of `localhost`.

So with default Docker networking what you want is not possible: a container cannot connect to the host’s `localhost`.

Docker also supports a special networking mode: [host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/). If you specify this when launching a container, it will not be put in a separate network namespace but instead use the host network namespace. The host’s and container’s `localhost` will be the same. However, there are implications:

- Port mappings will not be effective
- You need to take care not to use a port twice
- Host networking cannot be mixed with links

Depending on your setup, nginx losing access to other containers could not be acceptable.

You could instead use something like `socat` to make the port accessible to Docker containers:

```
docker run -d --restart=always --network=host alpine/socat TCP4-LISTEN:4001,fork,reuseaddr,interface=docker0 TCP4-CONNECT:localhost:4001
```

From your nginx container, you could then reach the host at 172.17.0.1 with default networking.

You can also try adding `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to the nginx container invocation to get a DNS name (`host.docker.internal`) that would then always work no matter the configuration. This only works in very recent versions of Docker.